# XAML Designer not loading and giving System.TypeLoadException exception

Tags: visual-studio, xaml-designer

The XAML Designer in my UWP project is not loading. It gives the following error.

```
System.TypeLoadException
Method 'GetStylePropertyTargetType' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Metadata.WindowsUIXamlPlatformMetadata' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UniversalXamlDesigner, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsStoreXamlPlatform..ctor(IPlatformRuntimeAssemblyResolver platformRuntimeAssemblyResolver, IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver platformReferenceAssemblyResolver)
```

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsPhoneXamlDesigner.WindowsPhoneXamlPlatform..ctor(IPlatformRuntimeAssemblyResolver platformRuntimeAssemblyResolver, IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver platformReferenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UniversalXamlDesigner.UniversalXamlPlatformCreator.CreatePlatformImpl(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver, IPlatformRuntimeAssemblyResolver runtimeAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsStoreXamlPlatformCreator.CreatePlatformInternal(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.PlatformCreatorBase.CreatePlatform(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

Can someone help me?

I tried the solutions available in all the similar questions asked, but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2539702/uwp-xaml-designer-is-broken)

> Programs and features -> Microsoft VS2015 -> Select Change -> Goto Modify and check if the SDK v1.3 is surely installed . if it didn't try to install it and double check the installation file and make sure that now sdk v1.3 is installed. If it weren't install and check over and over to be success at last . If you finally get success in installation of SDK v1.3 your XAML designer problem will surely gone

So this problem can be solved with installing SDK v1.3, make sure that you installed it and I strongly recommend you to repair Visual Studio after you install SDK.